# Floats not adding?

Tags: c, floating-point, addition

I'm trying to design a program to calculate and display how many seconds it will be until the current population reaches 8 billion. I think my logic is sound, but my while loop loops indefinitely and I can't figure out why.

I'm used to C++, but this is my first time writing in C so I'm wondering if there is some syntax issue I'm missing.

```
// Program to calculate population increase
// to see how many seconds from now
// the population will hit 8 billion

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float currentPop = 7600000000.0;
    float increasePerSec = 2.5;
    int secondCount = 0;

    printf("Counting...\n");

    while (currentPop < 8000000000.01)
    {
        currentPop += increasePerSec;
        secondCount++;
    }
    printf("It will be %f seconds from now.\n",secondCount);

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like the issue exists in this line:

```
currentPop += increasePerSec;
```

because the value always stays at 7.6 billion. Just in case I tried:

```
currentPop = currentPop + increasePerSec;
```

as well, but no change in result.

Comment: have you tried with a `double` instead of a `float` to get the extra precision for large floating point numbers?

Comment: Have you tried simple debugging by adding a `printf("%f", currentPop);` to in your while loop to see what's the value of currentPop?

Comment: Also `secondCount` is an integer, use `%d` instead of `%f`  while printing it.

Comment: Generally, population models do not assume the population increase is constant (because there are not a fixed number of people having babies) but that it is roughly proportional to the current population. After resolving the precision issue you have discovered, you might want to (a) consider a model with a proportional increase and (b) solve for time mathematically instead of by incrementally stepping a model through time.

Comment: Why not just calculate: (8.0e9 - 7.6e9) / 2.5 = 1.6e8 seconds (or: 160000000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a `float` is an IEEE754 single precision floating point type, it can only hold up to about 8 decimal digits of precision.  So adding the value 2.5 to 7600000000 is beyond the precision of what this type can hold, which means the result ends up being 7600000000.  So you have an infinite loop.

Change the data type to `double`, which has much more precision.  Then the loop should finish.

Also, you're using the `%f` format specifier to print `secondCount`, which is an int.  You should instead use `%d`.

Answer (score 7):

In the most commonly used format for `float`, IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary format, the representable values near 7600000000 are 7599999488, 7600000000, and 7600000512. This is because the 32-bit format uses only 24 bits for the significand (fraction portion). To represent 7600000000, the exponent must be set so the high bit of the significand represents 4294967296 (2<sup>32</sup>), which means the low bit represents 512 (2<sup>9</sup>). Therefore, increments to representable numbers at this point occur in units of 512.

When you add 2.5 to 7600000000, the mathematical result, 7600000002.5, is rounded to the nearest representable value, so the final result is 7600000000.

In the most commonly used format for `double`, there are 53 bits for the significand, so numbers with halves (2<sup>−1</sup>) can be represented up until 2<sup>53</sup> (9007199254740992).

Note: This answer assumes the common formats are in use. If greater portability is desired, a C implementation provides information about its floating-point information in the `<float.h>`. That information can be used to test whether the `float` or `double` formats provide sufficient precision.

Answer (score 0):

Just as addition, you may want to check the value of sizeof(float) on your computer, because the max value that can be stored in it  may be smaller than 7600000000.0 or 8000000000.01

Comment: I suspected this at first also, but according to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm it seems that float is 4 bytes, so it's highly unlikely this is the issue? It still might be though, who knows

Comment: The maximum value that can be stored in the common format for `float` is ∞, which is considerably larger than 7600000000. The maximum finite value that can be stored in it is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440, which is also considerably larger than 7600000000.

Comment: Could you clarify why the maximun value is ∞ ?

Comment: Assuming they are float32 types, then they use a base and an exponent, so they can even hold much more than 7.6e9. But the larger the number, the bigger the gaps between two exactly representable numbers.

Comment: @hamidcrazy: IEEE 754 defines one of the values of the floating-point type to represent infinity. When used in arithmetic, it behaves like infinity: Adding any finite number to infinity yields infinity, *et cetera*. When you print it, “inf” or “infinity” or some other representation of infinity is printed.